# Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 but the dependency don't exist

Tags: java, maven

I have this error `java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0`, in the deployment pipeline.

This is because the server have jdk 1.7 and commons-logging is compiled with jdk 1.8, the problem is, when a execute `mvn dependency:tree` commons-logging don't exist in the tree, the same if I execute with `-Dverbose`

And I searched with de IDE (IntelliJ) "LogFactory" in the code, in the dependency tree but I found nothing and I do not know who uses that dependency.

This is the result of `mvn dependency:tree`:

```
[INFO] cl.YYYY:bs-project-t:war:2.69.10-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- com.YYYY.lib.shared:common-libs:jar:1.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] +- com.YYYY.lib.shared:crypto-utils:jar:1.5.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.10:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.7:compile
[INFO] +- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-json-provider:jar:2.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-base:jar:2.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:jar:2.2.3:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.2.3:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.8.1:compile
[INFO] +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
[INFO] +- com.YYYY.lib.shared:spring-jar:jar:3.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.18.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.2.18.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:3.2.18.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:3.2.18.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:3.2.18.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.7.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:3.2.18.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-jms:jar:3.2.18.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:3.2.18.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.2.18.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.2.18.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.2.18.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.2.18.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:3.2.18.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-oxm:jar:3.2.18.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:3.2.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.2.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:3.2.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.ws:spring-ws-core:jar:2.4.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.ws:spring-xml:jar:2.4.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- com.YYYY.lib.shared:server-core:jar:1.4.4.SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- cl.YYYY:bankingrouter-common:jar:1.15.7-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- net.ttt.utils:resources-resolver:jar:1.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- cl.YYYY:mobile-configuration-model:jar:1.1.3-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-server:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- asm:asm:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-json:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.jettison:jettison:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- stax:stax-api:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-jaxrs:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-xc:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.jersey.contribs:jersey-multipart:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jvnet:mimepull:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.2.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- javax.xml.stream:stax-api:jar:1.0-2:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- jaxen:jaxen:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.3.02:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- xom:xom:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- xerces:xmlParserAPIs:jar:2.6.2:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- xalan:xalan:jar:2.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- com.ibm.icu:icu4j:jar:2.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.sf.json-lib:json-lib:jar:jdk15:2.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- net.sf.ezmorph:ezmorph:jar:1.0.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:jar:4.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-pool:commons-pool:jar:1.5.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jgroups:jgroups:jar:2.12.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk16:jar:1.46:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.ttt.cyberbank.view:ViewWidgetInterface:jar:1.0.3-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.lingala.zip4j:zip4j:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.owasp.esapi:esapi:jar:2.1.0:compile
[INFO] |     +- commons-configuration:commons-configuration:jar:1.5:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] |     +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils-core:jar:1.7.0:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.beanshell:bsh-core:jar:2.0b4:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.owasp.antisamy:antisamy:jar:1.4.3:compile
[INFO] |        +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-css:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |        |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-ext:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |        |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-util:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |        |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis-ext:jar:1.3.04:compile
[INFO] |        +- net.sourceforge.nekohtml:nekohtml:jar:1.9.12:compile
[INFO] |        \- commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] +- ma.glasnost.orika:orika-core:jar:1.4.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.16.1-GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.thoughtworks.paranamer:paranamer:jar:2.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap:concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru:jar:1.2_jdk5:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.carrotsearch:java-sizeof:jar:0.0.4:compile
[INFO] +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.5:compile
[INFO] +- net.sf.dozer:dozer:jar:5.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.8.3:compile
[INFO] +- com.oracle:ojdbc14:jar:10.2.0.3.0:compile
[INFO] +- cl.YYYY.cyberbank.v2.config:YYYY-tmf-config:jar:mobile:1.7.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- cl.YYYY.cyberbank.v2.cmm.bdm:cyberbank-custom-data-model:jar:1.1.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.ttt.cyberbank.cmm.bdm.helper:TECH-messaging-helper:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.ttt.assets.cyberbank.cmm:messaging-utils:jar:3.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- net.ttt.utils:zip-utils:jar:1.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- net.sf.saxon:saxon:jar:8.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.ttt.assets.cyberbank.cmm:oracle-weblogic-v10.3-dependencies:pom:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- weblogic:wlthint3client:jar:10.3.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.ttt.assets.cyberbank.cmm:websphere-message-broker-v70-dependencies:pom:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.ibm:com.ibm.mq.commonservices:jar:7.0.1.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.ibm:com.ibm.mq:jar:7.0.1.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.ibm:com.ibm.mq.headers:jar:7.0.1.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.ibm:com.ibm.mq.jmqi:jar:7.0.1.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.ibm:com.ibm.mq.pcf:jar:7.0.1.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.ibm:connector:jar:7.0.1.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.ibm:com.ibm.mqjms:jar:7.0.1.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- postgresql:postgresql:jar:8.1-404.jdbc3:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.ibm:db2jcc4:jar:4.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.ttt.logging:log4j-custom-fixes:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.ttt.techlog:techlog-client:jar:4.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- castor:castor:jar:0.9.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- concurrent:concurrent:jar:1.3.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.derby:derby:jar:10.1.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.0.1B:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- oro:oro:jar:2.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- spice:spice-jndikit:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- openjms:openjms:jar:0.7.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jasypt:jasypt:jar:1.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- net.ttt.techlog:techlog-contingency:jar:2.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- net.ttt.techlog:techlog-model:jar:4.2.2:provider
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.jibx:jibx-bind:jar:1.2.5:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |     +- bcel:bcel:jar:5.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |     |  \- regexp:regexp:jar:1.2:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |     \- com.thoughtworks.qdox:qdox:jar:1.12.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.mchange:c3p0:jar:0.9.2.1:provider
[INFO] |  |  |     \- com.mchange:mchange-commons-java:jar:0.2.3.4:runtime
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.ttt.multichannel:workflow:jar:13.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- jboss:jbpm:jar:3.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- jdom:jdom:jar:b9:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate:jar:3.2.5.ga:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- asm:asm-attrs:jar:1.5.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- cglib:cglib:jar:2.1_3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- c3p0:c3p0:jar:0.9.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- wsdl4j:wsdl4j:jar:1.6.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- wsdl4j:wsdl4j-qname:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springmodules:spring-modules-jbpm31:jar:0.8a:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- geronimo-spec:geronimo-spec-jta:jar:1.0.1B-rc4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- ehcache:ehcache:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- hsqldb:hsqldb:jar:1.7.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- cglib:cglib-nodep:jar:2.1_3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- bsh:bsh:jar:1.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- net.ttt.utils:xml-evaluator-api:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- net.ttt.techlog:extend-dialect:jar:1.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- net.ttt.utils:dummy-manager:jar:2.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- xpp3:xpp3:jar:1.1.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.sun.jndi:fscontext:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.sun.jndi:providerutil:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.ibm:dhbcore:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.ibm.mq.jms.context:mqcontext:jar:2.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.ttt.multichannel:tmf:jar:9.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- net.ttt.logging:log4j-custom-layouts:jar:1.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- net.ttt.assets.cache:cacheAPI:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.ttt.connectionpool:connection-pool:jar:2.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.jms:jms:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.ttt.cyberbank.assets.css:client-side-services:jar:1.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.ttt.cyberbank.assets:cache:jar:2.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.aop:jboss-aop:jar:2.1.8.GA:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.jcs:jcs:jar:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.ttt.multichannel.css:massiveSelectAgrupationProduct:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.ttt.multichannel.css:massiveSelectAlertContextByFilter:jar:1.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.ttt.multichannel.css:insertAlertContext:jar:1.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.ttt.multichannel.css:processEntryToSetUpUri:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.ttt.multichannel:workflow-services-config-manager-action:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- net.ttt.assets.cyberbank.cmm:populate-channel-data-action:jar:2.0.0:compile
[INFO] +- net.ttt.widgets:mostrarTelefono:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] +- net.ttt.widgets:buttonWeb:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] +- net.ttt.widgets:widget-cmr-puntos:jar:1.2-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] +- net.ttt.widgets:staticTextWidget:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] +- net.ttt.widgets:widget-clave-dinamica:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] +- net.ttt.widgets:buttonLink:jar:1.2-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] +- net.ttt.widgets:textMessageCustomWidget:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] +- net.ttt.widgets:stepFieldWidget:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] +- net.ttt.widgets:textMessageAlignLeftRightWidget:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] +- net.ttt.widgets:groupDefinitionWidget:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] +- net.ttt.widgets:widget-progressBar:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] +- net.ttt.assets.cyberbank.cmm:root-messaging-model:jar:4.5.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jibx:jibx-run:jar:1.2.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jibx:jibx-extras:jar:1.2.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jdom:jdom:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.ws.security:wss4j:jar:1.6.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.santuario:xmlsec:jar:1.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.opensaml:opensaml:jar:2.5.1-1:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.opensaml:openws:jar:1.4.2-1:compile
[INFO] |  |        \- org.opensaml:xmltooling:jar:1.3.2-1:compile
[INFO] |  \- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.9.1:compile
[INFO] +- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.9.9:compile
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.mockito:mockito-all:jar:1.10.19:compile
[INFO] +- org.mock-server:mockserver-netty:jar:3.10.8:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mock-server:mockserver-client-java:jar:3.10.8:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mock-server:mockserver-core:jar:3.10.8:test
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.0.1:test
[INFO] |  |  +- io.netty:netty-codec-socks:jar:4.1.12.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  +- com.jcraft:jzlib:jar:1.1.3:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.bouncycastle:bcmail-jdk15on:jar:1.56:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:jar:1.56:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.2.3:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.json:json:jar:20090211:test
[INFO] |  |  \- com.github.fge:json-schema-validator:jar:2.2.6:test
[INFO] |  |     +- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:3.0.0:test
[INFO] |  |     +- com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:jar:6.2:test
[INFO] |  |     +- com.github.fge:json-schema-core:jar:1.2.5:test
[INFO] |  |     |  +- com.github.fge:uri-template:jar:0.9:test
[INFO] |  |     |  |  \- com.github.fge:msg-simple:jar:1.1:test
[INFO] |  |     |  |     \- com.github.fge:btf:jar:1.2:test
[INFO] |  |     |  +- com.github.fge:jackson-coreutils:jar:1.8:test
[INFO] |  |     |  \- org.mozilla:rhino:jar:1.7R4:test
[INFO] |  |     +- javax.mail:mailapi:jar:1.4.3:test
[INFO] |  |     \- net.sf.jopt-simple:jopt-simple:jar:4.6:test
[INFO] |  +- io.netty:netty-buffer:jar:4.1.12.Final:test
[INFO] |  +- io.netty:netty-codec:jar:4.1.12.Final:test
[INFO] |  +- io.netty:netty-codec-http:jar:4.1.12.Final:test
[INFO] |  +- io.netty:netty-common:jar:4.1.12.Final:test
[INFO] |  +- io.netty:netty-handler:jar:4.1.12.Final:test
[INFO] |  +- io.netty:netty-transport:jar:4.1.12.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  \- io.netty:netty-resolver:jar:4.1.12.Final:test
[INFO] |  +- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:jar:1.56:test
[INFO] |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:18.0:test
[INFO] |  +- janino:janino:jar:2.5.10:test
[INFO] |  \- org.mock-server:mockserver-logging:jar:3.10.8:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:3.2.18.RELEASE:test
[INFO] \- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:1.10.19:test
[INFO]    \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.1:test
```

Comment: `LogFactory` might be packaged in some other dependency.

Comment: @lexicore I thought so but I can not find what it can be.

Comment: Here's an idea: add `commons-logging` to dependencies and run an analysis with [Tattletale](http://docs.jboss.org/tattletale/developerguide/1.2/en-US/html/introduction.html). Tattletale should complain about duplicate classes, hopefully naming the dependency to blame.

Comment: Another idea: do you deploy to an appserver like Tomcat or similar? Maybe `commons-logging` is somewhere there in libraries? Does it start without your app?

Comment: And maybe try `java -verbose:class` if nothing else helps.

Comment: @lexicore I add `commons-logging` v1.0 and works. Anyway, I'm going to run the analysis with Tattletale. Thanks.

Comment: Please comment when you've found the cause. I'm puzzled.